# How to get the value of Codemirror textarea

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am using Codemirror's plugin for textarea but I am not able to retrieve the value of textarea.

Code:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    mode: "text/x-csrc"
  });


function showCode()
{
    var text = editor.mirror.getCode();
    alert(text);
}
```

It is showing the error:

```
editor.getCode() is not a function.
```

Comment: what does `console.dir(editor.morror)` and `console.dir(editor)` show in chrome?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Try using `getValue()` instead of `getCode()`.

Pass in an optional argument into getValue(separator) to specify the string to be used to separate lines (the default is `\n`).

Comment: is there a way to get a reference to the text without calling getValue()? This function is really slow if you have a lot of text in the editor and it will lock the UI thread.

Comment: Is there a difference between `cm.getValue()` and `cm.doc.getValue()`?

Answer (score 46):

This works fine for me.

```
editor.getValue()
```

Answer (score 9):

In version 6 assuming you have your `EditorView` in variable `editor` then you do:

```
editor.state.doc.toString()
```

Comment: the only working answer is this

Answer (score 6):

**use your_editor_instance.getValue();**

It will work fine because there is no function named with the name `getCode()` in CodeMirror.

For setting value use `your_editor_instance.setValue();`

Answer (score 1):

**Version: 5**

According to the [Documentation](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api), you need now to do it like:

`doc.getValue(?separator: string) → string`

So in this example:

`editor.getDoc().getValue("\n")`

Answer (score 1):

I know you are using `textarea` but I hope this code will be useful for others!
I have this problem but with `article` tag, and this is my solution to getting all codes with jquery:

```
res_array = []
$.each($('article.code-draft span[role="presentation"]'), function(){
    res_array.push($(this).text())
});
console.log(res_array.join('\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for C++ Selenium instances where you are trying to capture the text returned in a CodeMirror text area:

```
var myText = this.WebDriver.ExecuteJavaScript<string>("return $editor[0].getValue()");
```

Where `[0]` is the index of the code mirror text area in the form.