# How to type using cypress .type() inside the codemirror editor?

Tags: codemirror, cypress, firepad

I am writing some `cypress` test for the Codemirror Editor. I have use `cypress` to type in the input field.

I am trying to achieve the `cy.type()` in the CodeMirror Editor. The Data I have in codemirror is inside the span.

```
<pre class=" CodeMirror-line " role="presentation"><span role="presentation" style="padding-right: 0.1px;"> &lt; h1 &gt; Welcome to your web project canvas! &lt; /h1&gt;</span></pre>
```

The cypress spec code
cy.get('pre.CodeMirror-line')
  .type('Cypress HTML Data')

I am not able to type some data using cypress.

I would appreciate if someone can help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not targeting the correct element in your spec code. You're doing `cy.get('pre.CodeMirror-line')`, but a `<pre>` tag is not a `cy.type()`-able element.

You need to get the hidden CodeMirror `<textarea>` instead. This can be selected using `.CodeMirror textarea`. The following JS is a demo spec that works on `codemirror.net`:

```js
describe('Codemirror', () => {
  it('can be tested using textarea', () => {
    cy.visit('https://codemirror.net/')
    // CodeMirror's editor doesn't let us clear it from the
    // textarea, but we can read the Window object and then
    // invoke `setValue` on the editor global
    cy.window().then(win => {
      win.editor.setValue("")
    })
    cy.get('.CodeMirror textarea')
    // we use `force: true` below because the textarea is hidden
    // and by default Cypress won't interact with hidden elements
      .type('test test test test', { force: true })
  })
})
```

Comment: That's perfect Brillant Lad!

Comment: Hey @Zach Bloomquist How do you clear the editor? I have tried cy.get('.CodeMirror textarea')
.clear()

Comment: @RahulThawal you'll have to access the global `editor` object and then `setValue` on it. I've updated the answer with an example that works on codemirror.net.

Comment: Thank you! Awesome!

Comment: Alternatively you can do the following: `cy.get('.CodeMirror-code').type(<your text>)`

Comment: A question on similar thread: How do I get text from the CodeMirror Editor?
I found an answer on this question that shows how I can do it in the page's JS.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285301/how-to-get-the-value-of-codemirror-textarea 

I am looking to do something in the Cypress test.

Comment: This did not work for me, I actually couldn't find the "editor" in the Window object when running Cypress

Comment: This might help @Eren555 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012319/how-can-i-clear-a-codemirror-editor-field-from-cypress/62014266#62014266